# Difference between creating a new fragment and getting an existing one from the manager on rotation

Tags: android, android-fragments

It seems whether I set retainInstance to true or not, when I rotate the device, I get an existing fragment. The difference is that if I set it to true, I get "test = yes!", otherwise I get "test = no!" after rotating the device after clicking the test button to change `test`. That is, the member variable is kept, if I retain the instance.

But as I have said, even if I do not retain it, I get an existing fragment from the manager, anyway (always get "Reusing existing" on rotation). In that case, if all member variables are lost and the views of the fragment are recreated, what are kept? What is the point of getting an existing instance of the fragment?

In the activity's onCreate,

```
    var frag = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.frame)

    if(frag == null)
    {
        frag = Fragment1.newInstance("", "");
    }
    else
    {
        Log.d("sss", "Reusing exsiting");
    }

    val transaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    transaction.replace(R.id.frame, frag)
    transaction.commit()
```

In the fragment,

```
var test = "no!";

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
{
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    Log.d("sss", "test = " + test);
    testButton.setOnClickListener {
        test = "yes!";
    }
}
```

Comment: *... I get an existing fragment.* - Unless you use setRetainInstance() that fragment was created by the FragmentManager after rotation to replicate the previous stack of fragments your app created. In onCreate() there is no point in re-adding the fragment, if you find it in the FragmentManager it means it is in the position it needs to be and ready to use(this is why you might want to get a reference to it, call methods on it, initialize some of its properties etc). *what are kept?* - what is saved in onSaveInstanceState() and the data stored with setArguments().

Comment: Actually, your comment was the most helpful to understand this, but since I cannot mark a comment as the answer, I marked one of the other answers. But, thank you for the comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have spent some hours trying to recreate your situation with different scenarios. First of all, I should point out that the life cycle of Fragments are in fact so complicated that during Google I/O 2018, one of the lead developers asked the audiences if `onCreate()` method of the `Activity` is invoked first or that of `Fragment`'s. And the answer was that, it depends on the SDK version. But they are focusing more and more on Compatibility Libraries and advice developers to use these to have a universal experience across different devices, as well as enjoying the new APIs that will do the job of dealing with Fragments, so much easier for us.

While looking at the documentation of [AppCompatActivity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity) class, I realized that this behavior is their way of dealing with fragments.

```
Protected methods
void    onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
Perform initialization of all fragments.

void    onDestroy()
Destroy all fragments.

void    onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
void    onPostResume()
Dispatch onResume() to fragments.

void    onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
Save all appropriate fragment state.

void    onStart()
Dispatch onStart() to all fragments.

void    onStop()
Dispatch onStop() to all fragments.
```

As you can see they "save all appropriate fragment state" in `onSaveInstanceState()`; meaning that the states will be restored later on, after the `Activity` gets destroyed and recreated. So in `onDestroy()` all fragments get destroyed and when the `Activity` is created again, they get recreated as well. To make sure, you could override these methods inside both `Fragment` and `Activity` and check the result. If you do not check `FragmentManager` for already attached fragments, `onCreate()` method of the `Fragment` will be called twice, once directly by you -adding as a new `Fragment`- and once by the `AppCompatActivity` itself.

About the `retainInstance = true`, the documentation says that it keeps the member variables during configuration changes and will cause a slight difference in the life cycle of the `Fragment`.

Answer (score 1):

**setRetainInstance(true)**

Control whether a fragment instance is retained across Activity re-creation (such as from a configuration change). This can only be used with fragments not in the back stack. If set, the fragment lifecycle will be slightly different when an activity is recreated:

**onDestroy()** will not be called (but **onDetach()** still will be, because the fragment is being detached from its current activity).

**onCreate(Bundle)** will not be called since the fragment is not being re-created.

**onAttach(Activity)** and **onActivityCreated(Bundle)** will still be called.